# Watir / MiniTest - Undefined local variable or method 'browser'

Tags: ruby, variables, watir, minitest

I have 66 watir scripts that I have been creating over the past week to automate testing on the clients website.

However I have recently found out about a test framework called MiniTest which I am trying to implement now.

The reason I have set the URL as a variable is because there are 5 different sites that these tests need to run on so when they want me to run my pack on a different website I just need to update that 1 variable and not in each individual test.

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require "watir-webdriver"

class MPTEST < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase

def setup()
    url = "http://thewebsite.com/"
    $browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
    $browser.goto url
end

def test_myTestCase
    $browser.link(:text, "Submit your CV").click
    sleep(2)
    $browser.button(:value,"Submit").click
    assert($browser.label.text.includes?("This field is required"))

def teardown
    $browser.close
end

end
```

When running that I receive the following output:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'browser' for #<MPTEST:0x4cc72f8>c:/directory stuff...
```

Any ideas?

EDIT I have browser working however now there is an issue with my assert:

New code:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require "watir-webdriver"

class MPTEST < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase

def setup()
    url ="http://thewebsite.com"
    $browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
    $browser.goto url
end

def test_myTestCase
    $browser.link(:text, "Submit your CV").click
    sleep(2)
    $browser.button(:value,"Submit").click
    assert($browser.label.text.includes?("This field is required"))
end

def teardown
    $browser.close
end

end
```

And the error is:

```
NoMEthodError: undefined method 'includes?' for "":String
```

Comment: Are you sure that the exception is coming from this part of the code? The exception suggests you have a `browser.something` somewhere instead of the `$browser.something` (ie missing the `$`).

Comment: Well this is all of the code and I can't see any browser missing the $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception

```
NoMEthodError: undefined method 'includes?' for "":String
```

Is due to strings, in this case the value returned by `$browser.label.text` do not have an `includes?` method.

The method you actually want is [`include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F) (no plural):

```
assert($browser.label.text.include?("This field is required"))
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me you can you use `@browser` instead of `$browser` (but the problem might be not in this code)